# How to keep NPAPI plugins alive in ExtJS tabbed views

Tags: plugins, browser, extjs, dhtml, npapi

I'm trying to use a custom video player NPAPI plugin (view FireBreath) inside an tabbed ExtJS application.  The plugin lives in one tab, and the others contain presentations of other non-video data.

When switching from tab to tab, the  element that contains the plugin is destroyed, and all plugin state is lost.  Is there any way to configure an ExtJS tabbed panel so that the html contained in it is not altered when switching to another tab (just hidden)?  The alternative is to re-populate the plugin state when returning to the tab, but this would be associated with an unacceptable delay (mostly while waiting for video key frames).

Thanks,
O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was about to consider a helper application as recommended above, or look into rewriting the plugin to be windowless.  Both might be more robust solutions for other JS frameworks.

Fortunately, the solution ended up being simpler than this, at least for ExtJS.  By default, ExtJS sets `"display: none"` on the tabbed view's div whenever it is undisplayed, which calls the plugin destructor.  After doing a little more looking through their enormous API, ExtJS has a parameter `hideMode` as part of the Ext.panel.Panel base class:

> 'display' : The Component will be hidden using the display: none style.
>
> 'visibility' : The Component will be hidden using the visibility: hidden style.
>
> 'offsets' : The Component will be hidden by absolutely positioning it out of the visible area of the document. This is useful when a hidden Component must maintain measurable dimensions. Hiding using display results in a Component having zero dimensions.
>
> Defaults to: "display"

Setting the parent Panel that contains the plugin to `hideMode: 'offsets'` fixed the problem perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your ExtJS approach, if you can solve it on that side that would of course be preferrable.

However, if you can't, you can avoid the reinitialization by moving the stream handling to a helper application that is running in the background. The plugin would launch it as needed and receive the stream data from it after registering for it.
The helper would be told when to kill a stream and possibly kill it by itself after some timeout (to avoid session leaks in case of crashing plugins etc.).